# How to fix the issue "The VirtualMerchant ID was not supplied in the authorization request"

Tags: php, api

i am using Virtual Merchant online payment.

i have one demo account :
https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/login.do 
Account ID: 002549 
User ID   : 002549 
Password  : Abcd.1234gd

the submitting form code:

```
<form action="https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_amount" value="75.00">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_merchant_id" value="002549">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_user_id" value="002549">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_pin" value="2R56WU">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_transaction_type" value="ccsale">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_show_form" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ssl_invoice_number" value="20131226">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_customer_code" value="test demo">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_email" value="demo@gmail.com">
<input type="submit" value="Pay Now" class="button1">
```

i got one test credit card number: 4005550000000019 from http://www.infomerchant.net/creditcardprocessing/credit_card_test_numbers.html

after submitting, the result is:[image]
after clicking the process button, the result is : [image]
the text is :

```
Error Code :    4000
Error Name :    VID Not Supplied
Error Message :     The VirtualMerchant ID was not supplied in the authorization request.
```

could you know how to fix it ? or any suggestion.

ssl_merchant_id: 002549 
ssl_user_id: 002549 
ssl_pin: 2R56WU (it is from demo account under menu: user=>change pin)

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask the payment  provider?

Comment: You don't mention whether you supplied the VirtualMerchant ID or not, and obviously the error message indicates that you didn't. What is the VirtualMerchant ID and do you have one?

Comment: i already write it in my code 002549 and 2R56WU (it is from demo account under menu: user=>change pin)

Comment: @FreshLover, I am also getting the same error while calling the Demo Url.  Do u have the fix for this Issue.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue. The culprit turned up on my end, before my form POSTed data to VirtualMerchant. Make sure the data/string(s) are properly encoded, without any stray white space.